# D2L interpretResult() Timeskew and Javascript

Tags: javascript, desire2learn

In API calls to the D2L SDK I get "Timestamp out of range" and a number.  The docs say this is from a timestamp skew between the server and the client. I see calls in the Java SDK to use [interpretResult()](http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/externaldocs/javadocs/javaclientlib/com/d2lvalence/idkeyauth/ID2LUserContext.html#interpretResult%28int,%20java.lang.String%29) to deal with this. How do I do this from javascript?

Answer (score 1):

Historically, the D2L Javascript client made use of JSONP in order to work within the limitations imposed by the traditional 'same origin policy'. Unfortunately, using this technique does not give the client requester direct access to the response body on any result other than an HTTP 200/OK result.

D2L has recently made improvements to the Javascript client library so that now, provided you host your calling Javascript on the same domain+port as your LMS, your calling Javascript can use AJAX instead of JSONP and should be able to cope with non-200 results, detect the time skew, and adjust accordingly. Please note that your script must be hosted on the same domain, with the same port, and using the same HTTP scheme (HTTP or HTTPS) as your LMS. Accordingly, please ensure that you're using the most recent version of the D2L Javascript client library.

Now, in the particular case of a clock skew (resulting in a 403 response), you can pass the response body from ajax/xmlhttprequest to `D2L.Util.calculateSkew()` and it will give you back a skew value. When you then call `D2L.ApplicationContext.createUserContext()` or `.createUserContextWithValues()`, then take an optional parameter (default 0) to accomodate a clock skew value.